# PlatformEffect failing to attach?

Tags: xamarin.forms, effects

I believe I am having trouble getting a PlatformEffect to attach.  It appears that it is resolving but not attaching.  Here is the PlatformEffect in an iOS library project named `EffectTestLib.iOS`:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName ("MyCompany")]
[assembly: ExportEffect (typeof (EffectTestLib.iOS.MyEffect), "MyEffect")]
namespace EffectTestLib.iOS {

    public class MyEffect : PlatformEffect {

        protected override void OnAttached () {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("Effect Attached");
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        protected override void OnDetached () {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged (System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs args) {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged (args);
        }
    }
}
```

So, if it attaches, it SHOULD output "Effect Attached" and throw a `NotImplementedException`.

Here is the PCL code for the application that uses this PlatformEffect:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EffectTest { 
    public class App : Application {
        public App () {
            MainPage = new ContentPage {
                Content = new StackLayout {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = {
                        new Label {
                            XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                            Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            var effect = Effect.Resolve ("MyCompany.MyEffect");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("effect=[{0}]",effect);
            MainPage.Effects.Add(effect);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice I am writing the PlatformEffect to the application's output to verify it is resolved.  If it doesn't resolve, I should see `effect=[Xamarin.Forms.NullEffect]`.

Here is the applications iOS platform code:
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Foundation;
    using UIKit;

```
namespace EffectTest.iOS
{
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate :     global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();
            new EffectTestLib.iOS.MyEffect ();

            LoadApplication (new App ());

            return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I am calling `new EffectTestLib.iOS.MyEffect ();` to be sure my library is loading.

Also, iOS platform project includes a reference to the `EffectTestLib.iOS` library.

So, when I run the application, this is what happens:

```
2016-04-06 10:17:18.342 EffectTest.iOS[26578:8696061] effect=[EffectTestLib.iOS.MyEffect]
```

So, the PlatformEffect is resolved correctly.  However, it does not output "Effect Attached" nor throw NotImplementedException.  Also note that, if I change a property of MainPage, MyEffect.OnPropertyChanged is never called.

Referring back to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/effects/creating/, it appears I am:

1. Creating a subclass of the PlatformEffect class
2. Overriding the OnAttached method
3. Overriding the OnDetached method
4. Adding a ResolutionGroupName attribute to the effect class.
5. Adding an ExportEffect attribute to the effect class.

And, referring back to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/effects/creating/#Consuming_the_Effect_in_C, it appears that I am adding the effect to the pages Effects collection.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Source code: https://github.com/baskren/PlatformEffect_issue

Comment: Repeating my response to Saket, it appears that PlatformEffects do work on Page elements in Android but not in iOS.  I've updated [the github sample project](https://github.com/baskren/PlatformEffect_issue) to illustrate this.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your project and modified the code for it to work,
it won't get called on MainPage ,
Observation is  ,on page its doesn't work , on Views it works(will edit this observation after details finding).
Try doing it this way.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EffectTest { 
    public class App : Application {
        public App () {
            var label = new Label();
            label.Effects.Add (Effect.Resolve ("MyCompany.EffectCheck"));
            MainPage = new RootPage ();
            var effect = Effect.Resolve ("MyCompany.EffectCheck");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("effect=[{0}]",effect);
            //MainPage.Effects.Add(Effect.Resolve ("MyCompany.EffectCheck"));
        }

        protected override void OnStart () {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep () {
        }

        protected override void OnResume () {
        }
    }
}

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EffectTest
{
    public class RootPage:ContentPage
    {
        public RootPage()
        {
            Content = new StackLayout () {
                Children = {
                    new Label ()
                }
            };
// this.Effects.Add(Effect.Resolve ("MyCompany.EffectCheck")); will not work
                    Content.Effects.Add(Effect.Resolve ("MyCompany.EffectCheck")); // it will work;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this.  It appears that PlatformEffects do work on Page elements in Android but not iOS.  I've updated [this sample github project](https://github.com/baskren/PlatformEffect_issue) to show this.